# View of scripture on:Is blasphemy forgivable or unforgivable and what is their atonement in hinduism?

Tags: gods, practice, sin, ignorance

Is blasphemy forgivable or not in hinduism for

A) Blasphemy by thoughts

B) Blasphemy by speech

C) Blasphemy by acts (intentional /unintentional)

***I also want to know what's the possible way of atonement for the three?***

Comment: Never seen any discussion on blasphemy in any Hindu scripture.

Comment: Read this one https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54094/22857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Purana texts do speak of Veda Ninda and Deva Ninda (Blasphemy) to be an unpardonable offence which is punished with hell/naraka in the afterlife.

Kurma Purana II.16

[image]

Markandeya Purana 14.44

[image]

Comment: If you clearly see" a brahmana who criticize vedas and devas ", now my question is . Is there punishment in hell for others but only brahmans(like no prayachhit for brahmins) but prayachhit for others??

Answer (score 1):

I saw the answer that gives verses on blasphemy. That answer is supplemented by the concept of offense against the divine name 'namaparadha' in one Vaishnava school.

> According to Chaitanya's system, the Divine Name must be repeated
> faultlessly in order to bear immediate fruit. This conception of
> namaparadha - faults committed in taking the Name, is peculiar to this
> school. They have been listed as ten: (1) disparaging genuine
> devotees, (2) regarding God as absolutely different from His names,
> form, qualities, etc., or as equal to lesser gods, (3) disregarding
> the spiritual preceptor, (4) speaking too lightly or contemptuously of
> sacred scriptures, (5) considering the glory of the Divine Name
> mentioned in the scriptures as mere eulogy, (6) considering the Divine
> Name to be imaginary, (7) committing sins repeatedly and intentionally
> on the strength of the Divine Name, (8) regarding the repetition of
> the Divine Name as equal to other religious practices, (9) imparting
> it to unworthy persons, (10) lacking taste for the chanting or hearing
> the Divine Name even after hearing of its excellences. These faults,
> however, can be rectified by chanting the Divine Name. As the Padma
> Purana puts it:
>
> The sin of those who commit offense to the Divine Name is remedied by
> the Name alone, and it bears that fruit if taken constantly.

**Meditation and other Spiritual Disciplines by Swami Swahananda**

Comment: I have doubt like passages from Swami Swahananda, vivekanand ,nikhilanand etc. Are used in answer but they are not scripture then why answers are given by them??

Comment: The rules of this website allow such an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Narada in Mahabharata severely criticizes people who don't worship Krishna -

> 'Those men that will not worship the lotus-eyed Krishna should be
> regarded as dead though moving, and should never be talked to on any
> occasion.'

- Section XXXVIII, Rajasuyika Parva, Mahabharata.

Comment: Not worshipping a God isn't the same as blasphemy though.

Comment: @Chatuskoti - Here Narada said this in the context of Shishupala insulting Krishna. So Narada probably do mean Blasphemy here.